# Remove blinking cursor from input field hack not working for Emojis

Tags: javascript, css, input, drop-down-menu

I want to remove the blinking cursor from an input field.

Backstory: This input field will be customized with JavaScript in order to behave like a select input field with a custom dropdown menu.

I only know this one css hack to get rid of the blinking cursor.

```
<input type="text" value="Text goes here" />
```

CSS:

```
input {
  color: transparent;
  text-shadow: 0 0 0 #000;
}
```

This works somewhat alright for text but if you want to display an emoji  it won't work.
The emoticon is loosing its color and is only gets rendered in black.

```
<input type="text" value="" />
```

Is there a solution?
I don't want to use .blur() on the input field as well.

```
<input type="text" value="" class="amount-input" style="pointer-events: none" readonly>
```

This isn't working for me as well because I want to add the JS behavior with a keydown addEventListener in which you can hide the custom dropdown menu when hitting esc.

Comment: _"The emoticon is loosing its color and is only gets rendered in black."_ - that's no different from the letters, only with those you didn't notice it, because those presumably were black to begin with. You are not displaying the actual character, but only its shadow - and that _can_ have only one color.

Comment: Your best bet would probably be to remove the text-shadow, and make both color and background of the input field transparent - and then show the user input in an element you place directly behind it. Matching the formatting and behavior of a div or span to that of an input field is tricky though - so I would use a second input field. (Since that one lies behind the "real" one and doesn't actually get focus, it won't show a text cursor either.)

Comment: Only I think this is a _really_ bad idea to begin with ... If you want text input from me, then I _want_ a cursor! I do not want to have to delete X characters via [del], and then have to type them in again afterwards, just because I accidentally wrote `Floobar` instead of the intended `Foobar`. No, I want my cursor, so that I can move it behind that `l` directly, and deliberately remove only that ...

Comment: Plus, what if the user accidentally _sets_ the cursor to a specific position? Even if you disabled cursor keys, it could probably still happen via a click into the field that already contains some text at this point. Now the _invisible_ cursor is not even at the end of the current value, so what I type will appear somewhere in the middle of that.

Comment: As you are sort of emulating a select element it might be useful if we could see that code as there may be some interaction between the cursor and what you have introduced which we can’t guess at.